# Soaarqube upgrade from 3.7.2 to 4.4. Hung during db upgrade

Tags: sonarqube

I am upgrading sonarqube from 3.7.2 to 4.4. DB migration taking more than 2 hours on "MergeMeasureDataIntoProjectMeasures". Here is the log.

```
2014.10.07 23:31:27 INFO  [DbMigration]
2014.10.07 23:31:27 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  RemoveActiveDashboardsLinkedOnUnsharedDashboards: migrating ===============
2014.10.07 23:31:27 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  RemoveActiveDashboardsLinkedOnUnsharedDashboards: migrated (0.0320s) ======
2014.10.07 23:31:27 INFO  [DbMigration]
2014.10.07 23:31:27 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  MergeMeasureDataIntoProjectMeasures: migrating ============================
2014.10.07 23:31:27 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- add_column(:project_measures, "measure_data", :binary, {:null=>true})
2014.10.07 23:31:27 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0.0080s
2014.10.07 23:31:27 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0 rows
```

Please let me know the solution, if you had faced similar issue.

Thanks
Vimal

Comment: That log file doesn't show that it takes two hours. It shows that it takes < 1s. I might be wrong but that information doesn't seem useful to me.

Comment: Can you please give more details of the log? And which DB are you using? This migration step is know to be potentially long depending on the volume of data in your DB.

Answer (score 0):

```
Thanks for quick reply Fabrice and kkuilla.

"RemoveActiveDashboardsLinkedOnUnsharedDashboards" has completed with in 1s. The issue was with "MergeMeasureDataIntoProjectMeasures"


Upgrade has been completed. 

678849 have been upgraded. hence it took 2.30 hours.

here is the log


2014.10.07 23:31:27 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  MergeMeasureDataIntoProjectMeasures: migrating ============================
2014.10.07 23:31:27 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- add_column(:project_measures, "measure_data", :binary, {:null=>true})
2014.10.07 23:31:27 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0.0080s
2014.10.07 23:31:27 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0 rows
2014.10.08 02:01:22 INFO  [o.s.s.d.m.MassUpdater]  678849 rows have been updated
2014.10.08 02:01:22 INFO  [DbMigration]  -- drop_table(:measure_data)
2014.10.08 02:01:23 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0.5570s
2014.10.08 02:01:23 INFO  [DbMigration]     -> 0 rows
2014.10.08 02:01:23 INFO  [DbMigration]  ==  MergeMeasureDataIntoProjectMeasures: migrated (8995.5290s) ================
```